Internal Server Error (500) on Vercel Deployment - Works Fine Locally
m encountering an issue where my application runs without any problems locally, but when I deploy it to Vercel, I receive a 500 Internal Server Error. I need some assistance to diagnose and fix this issue. Here are the details:

Project Overview:


Pintrest web app
Tech stack (Ejs, Node.js, Next.js, Expres.)


Error Details:

Error message from Vercel deployment logs:

500 internal Server Error. Function invocation Failed

vercel.json configuration file:
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "bin/www",
        "use": "@vercel/node"
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "/bin/www"
      }
    ]
  }

I appreciate any guidance or insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it. Thank you!
Checked the app on local server.
Checked the routes and models
Update vercel.json file
